# Question about weak self in static methods

Tags: ios, swift

I am using DispatchQueue.main.async in my ViewController and I'm not sure about using weak self. I've seen various articles about this with various opinions, some say that in static methods like this or UIView.animate you don't have to worry about weak self. Can anyone clarify this is alright or is this overkill? I've compiled with weak self and without and neither creates a memory leak.

```
    func updateDataDisplay() {
   
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self ] in
        guard let self = self else { return}
        self.comicTitle.text = self.comicViewModel.comicData?.title ?? "No Title Available"
        if self.comicViewModel.comicData?.img != nil {
            guard let imageURL = URL(string: (self.comicViewModel.comicData?.img)!) else { return}
            self.comicImage.load(url:imageURL)
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

this is overkill, I have the same confusion before, and I found the key. **we use weak reference in block is to avoid/break retain cycle**. if there is no retain cycle happens, we don't have to do it.

back to the code, the 'self' won't hold the dispatch block, no retain cycle will happen, so there is no need to use 'weak'.

Comment: It will not retain cycle but it can crash if the closure try to be executed when self was deallocated.